# log4j - DailyRollingFileAppender, file not roll hourly

Tags: log4j

I have the following simple Test class for DailyRollingFileAppender to rolls the log file every hour. The problem I am facing is that, it doesn't seem to roll over to new log file every hour even though I have set that to '.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH. Any idea where in the code I did wrongly?

```
public class Test {
  static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      String pattern = "%-20d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%-5p] - %m%n";

    PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout(pattern);  

    //CREATE APPENDER.       
    DailyRollingFileAppender myAppender = new DailyRollingFileAppender(patternLayout, "TestOrig.log", "'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH");

    //ADD APPENDER & LEVEL.
    logger.addAppender(myAppender);
    logger.setLevel   ((Level) Level.DEBUG);


//WRITE MESSAGES.
logger.debug("Successful");
logger.info ("Failed" );
logger.warn ("Failed" );
logger.error("Successful");
logger.fatal("Failed"); 

    while(true)
    {           
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use @Singleton and @Schedule to create an ejb cron like schedule for your timer service.

```
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;


@Singleton
public class Cron {
        static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);
    @Schedule(second="0", minute="0", hour="0", dayOfWeek="*", persistent=false)
    public void rollLogs() {
        logger.info("midnight");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error here.  I could see this is creating files when I tried for minutes.

```
DailyRollingFileAppender myAppender = new DailyRollingFileAppender(patternLayout, "TestOrig.log", "'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm");
```

Did you see any error on the console??

Possible reason of error for you could be , you are trying to run the same program multiple times, without ending the previously started program and that is resulting in file access permission issue.

Comment: Well, I see the behaviour here with log4j, if there is no logging activiting going on after an hour, it will not rename the log file to TestOrig.log.2011-10-14-14. Only when I shutdown the app and startup again, then it will create that file. Is there any way that I can force it to create TestOrig.log.2011-10-14-14 if even there is no log event going on?

Comment: No, It will roll over whenever next logevent comes to it and while logging that it checks whether it is time to rollover or not.See Javadoc of subAppend(LoggingEvent event)  in DailyLogAppender for details.

Answer (score 0):

Mike, you are correct in your comment above.  You will not get a new file unless there is logging activity during that time.  If you are required to force the issue, you'll need to start a thread with a runnable that posts a line to the log after the start of each new hour.

The goal is to make one post to your log every 59.5 minutes, starting from minute 1.

Basic standard knowledge of how to use Runnable and Thread are required for his solution.  I am assuming you are running a standard application and not within a managed server environment

1. create a class that implements `Runnable`
2. overwrite the `run()` method with a `while` loop to a `true` boolean variable (isAlive) your app can set to `false` when your app shuts down.
3. during the loop call the `.info("Logger Text")` method of a `static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(YourClassName.class);` with a loop wait time of 60 minutes.
4. Toss the `Runnable` into a `new Thread()` object at application start-up
5. make one `info()` post to your log at startup.
6. start the thread object when you start your app.

run() method of Runnable can be

```
public void run() { 
    while (isAlive) { // isAlive is a global-level (static, even) boolean 
                      // you declared earlier as true, your app should set it to false
                      // if your app decides to exit

        try { 
            logger.info("Rollover Log Text");
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000 * 60 * 60); // 60 minutes 
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) { 
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to set `isAlive` to `true` before you start your `Thread`, set it to `false` on shutdown or error/exception close, and call the the `interrupt()` method of your thread after setting to `false`.  This should log one time an hour.

Comment: Hi Fred, thanks for clarifying the fact. Can you provide an example of how to perform this runnable thread to check every new hour and trigger the logging event as I am very new to log4j. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mike - Basic standard knowledge of how to use Runnable and Thread are required.  Assuming you are running in a standard application and not within a managed server environment, (1) create a class that implements Runnable, (2) overwrite the run() method with a while loop to a true boolean that you can flag to false when your app shuts down, and during the loop call the info("Logger Text") method of a static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(YourClassName.class) with a loop wait time of 59 minutes.  Toss the runnable into a new thread , and start the thread when you start the app.

Comment: Answer requires knowledge of Thread use over knowledge of log4j; the goal is to make one post to your log every 59.5 minutes.

run() method of Runnable can be
'public void run() {
  while (staticBooleanAppIsAlive) {
    try {
        staticLogger.info("Rollover Log Text");
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000 * 60 * 59.5);  // 59.5 minutes
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
  }
}'

And remember to set staticBooleanAppIsAlive and call the interrupt() method of your thread at app shutdown.
This logs one time an hour; experiment on your own to figure out what time to set for sleep.

Comment: @mike - Edited my answer to include comments.